# How to measure body fitness

Tags: supplement, sports, body-weight, walking, body-mass-index-bmi

I am wondering if here is any clue/algorithm/generally well recognized equation to measure body fitness according to/considering average daily/periodic step count data, walking distance, sports and workout time, burned calories, sleep time, rest time, consumed food ingredients, cosumed vitamins, persons age, height, gender etc. parameters.

Any article on that section will also be appreciated?